# Zooming and Panning in JS/JQuery like we can do it using SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating an org chart with thousands of nodes but created a sample example here,

https://jsfiddle.net/jy6j87g0/2/

As you can see zooming and panning is working but I would like to make it work like one here,

http://live.yworks.com/demobrowser/index.html#Organization-Charts

**To be specific**

I am trying to make my fiddle,

- To zoom based on mouse pointer's position not centre of chart
- Have a limit on minimum size my chart can go so it won't go invisible
- Have a reset button

I am struggling to find where to start, should I look further into CSS transformation or use d3.js instead and create everything from scratch.

`Link to library` - https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart

```js
'use strict';

(function($) {

  $(function() {

    var datascource = {
      'name': 'Lao Lao',
      'title': 'general manager',
      'children': [{
        'name': 'Bo Miao',
        'title': 'department manager'
      }, {
        'name': 'Su Miao',
        'title': 'department manager',
        'children': [{
          'name': 'Tie Hua',
          'title': 'senior engineer'
        }, {
          'name': 'Hei Hei',
          'title': 'senior engineer',
          'children': [{
            'name': 'Pang Pang',
            'title': 'engineer'
          }, {
            'name': 'Xiang Xiang',
            'title': 'UE engineer'
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        'name': 'Yu Jie',
        'title': 'department manager'
      }, {
        'name': 'Yu Li',
        'title': 'department manager'
      }, {
        'name': 'Hong Miao',
        'title': 'department manager'
      }, {
        'name': 'Yu Wei',
        'title': 'department manager'
      }, {
        'name': 'Chun Miao',
        'title': 'department manager'
      }, {
        'name': 'Yu Tie',
        'title': 'department manager'
      }]
    };

    $('#chart-container').orgchart({
        'data': datascource,
        'nodeContent': 'title',
        'pan': true,
        'zoom': true
      })
      .on('touchmove', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/css/jquery.orgchart.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/js/jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container">
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Couldn't this library render an SVG instead of HTML tables? For SVGs I use the svg-pan-zoom (https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) library with great success so far.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási I believe it doesn't at least at the moment

Comment: Also, if you have a chance I'd like to mention highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com) library, which is an extremely powerful stuff, and has this feature built-in I guess.

Comment: As far as I know, it's free for non-commercial use. I used it in a project fitting to this, that's why it's in my mind, but you're right in general.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási it's for commercial use unfortunately in my case. Thanks for info though

Comment: @Mathematics if you have thousands of nodes you're going to need a different strategy, especially on mobile. Also, why don't you just use SVG? It was designed for this sort of task. I'd recommend just using svg with javascript (take a look at snap.js or d3). Also, I would not reveal all levels of the hierarchy simultaneously if you don't need to. If you do, then you may need a much more powerful engine. Also note, if you use HTML and use absolute positioning a lot, you may find the performance benefits you were counting on disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet below fulfills the 3 requirements set out in your question:

1. The zoom is centered on the mouse position
2. The scaling cannot go below MIN_ZOOM = 0.25
3. The Reset button restores the original position and scaling

The transform matrix and the mouse position observed in the `mousemove` event handler are stored in module variables, and used later in the `wheel` event handler.

In my tests, the `wheel` event was always triggered after the scaling had been processed by OrgChart. If this processing order is not the same in your case, or not stable, you can wrap the code of the `wheel` event handler in a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` construct to make sure that the scaling has already been performed by OrgChart:

```
.on("wheel", function (event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Process the event after OrgChart
        (put the code here)
    }, 0);
}
```

```js
'use strict';

(function ($) {

    $(function () {

        var datascource = {
            'name': 'Lao Lao',
            'title': 'general manager',
            'children': [{
                'name': 'Bo Miao',
                'title': 'department manager'
            }, {
                'name': 'Su Miao',
                'title': 'department manager',
                'children': [{
                    'name': 'Tie Hua',
                    'title': 'senior engineer'
                }, {
                    'name': 'Hei Hei',
                    'title': 'senior engineer',
                    'children': [{
                        'name': 'Pang Pang',
                        'title': 'engineer'
                    }, {
                        'name': 'Xiang Xiang',
                        'title': 'UE engineer'
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                'name': 'Yu Jie',
                'title': 'department manager'
            }, {
                'name': 'Yu Li',
                'title': 'department manager'
            }, {
                'name': 'Hong Miao',
                'title': 'department manager'
            }, {
                'name': 'Yu Wei',
                'title': 'department manager'
            }, {
                'name': 'Chun Miao',
                'title': 'department manager'
            }, {
                'name': 'Yu Tie',
                'title': 'department manager'
            }]
        };

        var MIN_ZOOM = 0.25; // Mimimum value for scaling
        var defaultMatrix = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]; // Chart at normal scaling and position
        var prevMatrix = defaultMatrix;
        var prevPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 };

        var parseNumber = function (str) {
            return parseFloat(str.replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, ""));
        }

        var getTransformMatrix = function () {
            var transform = $(".orgchart").css("transform");
            if (transform !== 'none') {
                var tokens = transform.split(",");
                var matrix = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                    matrix.push(parseNumber(tokens[i]));
                }
                return matrix;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        };

        var setTransformMatrix = function (matrix) {
            $(".orgchart").css("transform", "matrix(" + matrix.join(",") + ")");
            prevMatrix = matrix;
        };

        var getMousePosition = function (event) {
            var rect = $(".orgchart")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: event.clientX - rect.left - rect.width / 2,
                y: event.clientY - rect.top - rect.height / 2
            }
        };

        $("#btnReset").click(function () {
            setTransformMatrix(defaultMatrix);
        });

        $("#chart-container").orgchart({
            'data': datascource,
            'nodeContent': 'title',
            'pan': true,
            'zoom': true
        }).on("touchmove", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }).on("mousemove", function (event) {
            // Remember transform matrix and mouse position
            prevMatrix = getTransformMatrix() || prevMatrix;
            prevPosition = getMousePosition(event);
        }).on("wheel", function (event) {
            // In my tests, this event is triggered after processing has been done by OrgChart
            // If not the case, the following code can be wrapped in setTimeout(fn, 0) call
            var $this = $(this);
            var matrix = getTransformMatrix();
            if (matrix) {
                var $orgchart = $(".orgchart");

                // Prevent scaling below minimum zoom
                matrix[0] = Math.max(matrix[0], MIN_ZOOM);
                matrix[3] = Math.max(matrix[3], MIN_ZOOM);

                var position = getMousePosition(event);

                // Calculate expected mouse position with new scaling
                // corresponding to previous mouse position with old scaling
                var expectedPosition = {
                    x: prevPosition.x * matrix[0] / prevMatrix[0],
                    y: prevPosition.y * matrix[3] / prevMatrix[3]
                };

                // Translate chart position to match the expected position
                matrix[4] += position.x - expectedPosition.x;
                matrix[5] += position.y - expectedPosition.y;

                setTransformMatrix(matrix);
                prevPosition = expectedPosition;
            }
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
#btnReset
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    top: 16px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/css/jquery.orgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/js/jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
<button id="btnReset">Reset</button>
<div id="chart-container">
</div>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work atm. The problem is likely GitHub preventing linking to js files (specifically the jquery.orgchart.js link). I know the links are originally from OPs post (which neither works atm), but the links should really go through a CDN such as rawgit.com (as in the first link). rawgit won't use links to github.io sites though but will require the rep-link as source. If you test make a hard reload first as you probably have the files in the cache. Snapshot: http://i.imgur.com/zLFVSSC.png

Comment: @K3N - Thanks for the info. I haven't seen that problem on my side yet. I assume that it lasted only a few minutes. I found one [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-orgchart) for OrgChart, but it did not work when I tried it.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thank you, it works in JSFiddle but not in my local setup, I am not sure why, I will investigate and come back to you, thank you so much :)

Comment: It could be caused by the event processing order. You can eliminate that possibility with the `setTimeout` construct that I mention just above the code snippet (you can try it with 10 or 50 milliseconds instead of 0).

Comment: @ConnorsFan I couldn't make it work in my work environment and I tested it on fiddle with larger dataset, other then it being slow to drag and pan around it worked fine for zooming... so I am awarding you bounty, other then that as you already know I changed my methodology and now using d3.js, I may come back to this in future. thanks again